# Wrong dns suffix is appended

Tags: windows-7, vpn, dns

I use Win7 inside a vpn, and my organization have a few dns suffixes that are used:

```
a.myorg
b.myorg
c.myorg
```

and I'm using the server `server.c.myorg`.

And some of the time when I do `ping server`, the correct suffix is appended, and the correct ip is resolved.

but on other times, `ping server` will try to ping `server.a.myorg`, get a weird ip (`10.10.10.10`) and fail.

I did `nslookup` to the dns servers with those results:

`server` -> correct ip

`server.c.myorg` -> correct ip

`server.a.myorg` -> non existing domain

I'm trying to figure why some of the time the incorrect suffix is being appended.

Comment: Why would you expect your DNS resolver to know to append the third search domain in the list instead of the first?

Comment: the same setup worked in the past. I think that the resolver tries all of the suffixes and will use the first one that exists. That means that some how the resolver gets an ip for `server.a.myorg`. I just can't figure out from where